# iPhone simulator isn't showing splash screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios-simulator

All I have to do to show a splash screen in a view-based application is drag an image into the resources folder and name it default.png, correct? This is what I did, but the image doesn't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you added it, did you tell it to copy to output location?  It was a checkbox on the dialog that showed up after you added it.  Try readding and make sure this checkbox is checked.

UPDATE from comments: a clean build fixed the problem

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't do anything. Is there something else that needs to be done to make this work?

Comment: Try doing a clean build and resetting the simulator before running.  Perhaps your changes aren't getting to the simulator.

Comment: Also, is your PNG definitely not corrupt?

Comment: How can the PNG be checked for corruption? I just took a JPG and saved it as a PNG.

Comment: Doing a clean build is what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are doing is correct, but reading through the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12) might help you work out what the problem is.

Perhaps your `Default.png` is not in the root of your bundle? To check, expand the Products section in the Groups & Files panel, then select Reveal in Finder from the context menu. Then right click on the app bundle in Finder, and select Show Package Contents. You should see your `Default.png` listed there.

Comment: When I reveal the file in finder, I can see it is there in the same directory as the app bundle. But when I show the package contents of the app bundle I don't see it in there.