# IPhone App Load Screen

Tags: iphone, view, navigation, loading

When my application first loads on the iphone it throws up a black screen for about 1/2 a second than it goes into the app. Im just wondering what screen this is that first shows on load? I would like to edit it so i can show my logo on it so the user doesnt just get a black screen.

It is an application based off the standard navigation template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383812/iphone-simulator-isnt-showing-splash-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an image shown on application startup - if it is named `Default.png` - it will be used by default. Or you can specify image name in "Launch image" field in application plist file.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [Human Interface Guidelines for the launch image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5), note that they recommend not to use a branding logo for this image. Documentation about which default launch images you can define is in the [Application Launch Images](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12) section.